# What's the fastest way to shift several unsigned chars at once so they flow from one to the other?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, arduino, bit-shift

We have the following array...

```
unsigned char pixelData[16][5]
```

...which represents a 40x16 1bpp display used to feed a LED matrix.

Shifting our drawing up or down a single pixel at a time is easy as we just change the first indexer.  However, since the second indexer represents an entire byte, not a single pixel, we're not sure the most efficient way to shift the data left or right.

My first thought would be to do it pixel-by-pixel, but that of course would be pretty slow requiring eight operations per byte.

My next thought was to shift each byte left or right, but storing the shifted-out bit for replacement in the one next to it. That drops it to three ops per byte (store, shift, replace) but it also makes the logic complex if you wanted to shift more than a single pixel at a time, as you'd also need a mask.

My thought after that was to cast specific members of the array to uint16_ts so I could work on them with a 16-bit length instead of 8, which would reduce the steps from 6 (store/shift/replace x 2) to four (cast/store/shift/replace)... but I still have to think there's a faster way to do this. Again though, if you're shifting more than one place, you're right back to the masking issue.

That said, what's the most efficient way to shift an entire row of bytes?

If it matters, this is on an Atmel chip, specifically on Arduinos.

Answer (score 3):

If you're open to including some assembler in your code, Atmel AVR uC have the perfect instruction for this purpose : ROR or ROL. They make a bit shift with carry retaining and last carry insertion.
ROR(x) : x[b7] = Carry; x = x >> 1; Carry = x[b0]

You would just have to execute this instruction 5 times to get exactly what you're looking for.

**EDIT**: something like that in Arduino IDE should do the trick (I haven't tested it):

```
asm ("rol %0" : "=r" (pixelData[16][0]) : "0" (pixelData[16][0]));
asm ("rol %0" : "=r" (pixelData[16][1]) : "0" (pixelData[16][1]));
asm ("rol %0" : "=r" (pixelData[16][2]) : "0" (pixelData[16][2]));
asm ("rol %0" : "=r" (pixelData[16][3]) : "0" (pixelData[16][3]));
asm ("rol %0" : "=r" (pixelData[16][4]) : "0" (pixelData[16][4]));
```

The bitflow would be:

```
ROL <value>:
    # Carry Register = 8th bit of the given value
    # value = value << 1
    # 1st bit of the value = Previous Carry Register)

ROL 0b10000001 # Result = 0b00000010 and Carry = 1
ROL 0b10000001 # Result = 0b00000011 and Carry = 1
ROL 0b00000001 # Result = 0b00000011 and Carry = 0
ROL 0b00000001 # Result = 0b00000010 and Carry = 0
```

Comment: Can you give a simple code example in your answer?  Never used assembly in Arduino code before but I do know its possible.  If it makes it easier, just use a 1d array.  Question though... if I wanted to shift it three pixels to the left, I'd have to call this fifteen times, right (5 times per pixel, times three pixels)?

Comment: And actually, looking at this, doesn't this rotate the bit from one end of the byte to the other?  I want the bit shifted out of byteA to be shifted into byteB.  In other words, carrying from one to the other, not around in the same byte.

Comment: You're on the right track, look for RRX __Rotate Right w/Extend__ (It's the only one that rotates __through__ CARRY. ARM Reference: http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0489c/CIHDDCIF.html

Comment: @lornix Arduino uses an Atmel AVR microcontroller, not an ARM chip. According to the [instruction set](http://www.atmel.com/images/doc0856.pdf): ROL means Rotate Left Through Carry:  `Rd(0) ← C; Rd(n+1) ← Rd(n); C ← Rd(7);`, and similar for ROR.

Comment: Oh! Sorry, right idea, wrong instruction set!  Carry on!  Nothing to see here... move along! :)

Comment: @Pepito, does this carry through all of the bytes, flowing from one to the other?  Any chance you can show pseudo-output with your code example?  I ask because my understanding of ROL and ROR was not to go from byte to byte, but rather to rotate around the same byte, but I admit, I'm a complete newbie here to assembler.

Comment: Well, ROL and ROR does rotate one byte, but they also do 2 additional things: retain the poped-out bit, and push-in the last retained bit.